# How can I create a dataframe using variables from an existing column as columns using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, spyder, analysis

Example :

[image: Original dataframe]

I want save it as the below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

## Read the data in as a pandas dataframe.

df = pd.read_csv("path")

## Transpose the dataframe.

df_t = df.T

print(df_t)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, thats what I wanted to do.

Comment: No problem! However, for future posts, make sure to accept the correct answer. Also, comments are reserved for information/questions etc.